# Command to get svn diff of current and previous revision number

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How can I get diff in file content of current and previous revision number by command line?

And how can I get previous revision number?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As per your comments you'd like to see differences between the current and previous versions of an item that is not in your working copy. For that you need to know the item's URL (e.g. `svn://[repo_root]/[path]/[item]`) which I assume you do. Then you do the following:

```
svn info <item-URL>
```

will contain (among other things) the last change revision. With that revision number R you run:

```
svn diff -c <R> <item-URL>
```

and it will give you the last commit diff.

Answer (score 98):

`svn diff -r HEAD <item>` if you want to get the difference between your working copy and the last committed revision.

`svn diff -r PREV:COMMITTED <item>` if you want to see what the last commit did.

You should take look at [Revision Keywords](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.keywords).

`svn info <item>` will give you (among other things) the last change revision for the item.

Comment: `svn diff -r COMMITTED:PREV` then.

Comment: I deleted my comment because I wanted to edit it. So please update your  answer.

Comment: Go ahead and edit it, or post your own answer. I don't think I fully understand what the OP wants. If you do, please edit or answer :]

Comment: I posted my own, but then deleted it as yours is better. I'll edit it.

Comment: Actually i wanted to get diff of last two svn revision number not from my current working working directroy

Comment: Ok, then I'll resurrect my answer.