# Find the last commit to have changed a file

Tags: windows, svn

## Question

Using the `svn` command line, I would like to find the last commit that touched a file. Here it is in pseudo-code:

```
svn log -v --search my-file.txt --first-match
```

## What I have tried:

```
svn log -v --search my-file.txt -l 1
```

Unfortunately, this only searches the most recent commit. It doesn't return the first match.

```
svn log my-file.txt -v -l 1
```

Subversion complains that:

> svn: E155010: The node 'C:\Users\my.user\Documents\SubversionSvn\MyDir\my-file.txt' was not found.

```
svn log svn://my.server.com/svn/path/to/my-file.txt
```

Svn complains that:

> svn: E160013: File not found: revision 427, path '/svn/path/to/my-file.txt'

Comment: Is `my-file.txt` in the repository?  Couldn't you just get the log of that file?

Comment: @PatrickQuirk Yes. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Just get the log of the file and limit it to the first (most recent) entry:

```
svn log my-file.txt -v -l 1
```

If the file was in your repository but was deleted, you'll need to pass a [peg revision](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html) so SVN knows what file you're asking about:

```
svn log my-file.txt@3511 -v -l 1
```

Here, the peg revision is 3511 which is the last revision where the file existed before it was deleted from the repository.  However you've already answered your question once you've found this number.

If the file was never in the repository (it isn't now, based on your errors), then this isn't a question that SVN can answer for you.

Comment: I'm receiving an error saying, "svn: E155010: The node 'path\to\my-file.txt' was not found."

Comment: That means it's not in the repository, i.e. it's not under version control.  Try to pass the full repository path to it if you're sure it's  under version control, i.e. `svn log http://your.server.com/svn/path/to/my-file.txt`

Comment: What does it mean to be in the repository? For instance, `svn log -v --search my-file.txt` returns lots of results. So, it's in the history. Doesn't that mean it's in the repository?

Comment: I'm afraid passing the full repository path also failed with a file not found message.

Comment: The file must not be in the repository then (by that I mean added and committed using SVN).  The [`--search` switch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.search) you used searches for the string "my-file.txt" in log messages, not the files that were modified

Comment: BTW, `--search` and `--search-and` usage examples are given at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk When we pass `-v` the `--search` also looks through the files that were modified.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk The file is in the repository. I just checked it out from a previous revision.

Answer (score 0):

I use GUI , go to file on your comp, right click on file , TortoiseSVN > Diff with previous version

[Link for command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618438/command-to-get-svn-diff-of-current-and-previous-revision-number)